# WPF: How can I observe a List property of an observed object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called `Item` and an `ObservableCollection<Item>` in my viewmodel object. I've bind it to a `ListBox`. But `Item` has a field called `Stats` which is a `List<Stat>` and I want to bind it to another `ListBox`. I can't make it an `ObservableCollection` because both `Item` and `Stat` are part of a separate class library which will be used in non-wpf projects. I'm developing them both so I can make any changes I want but I can't figure out how I should go about doing this.

I'm trying to develop an editor so one can select an Item from the first list and add Stats to the selected Item(and further customize those stats too).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify Item to hold something other than a `List<StatModifer>` then you can't do what you want. You will need to make a `ItemViewModel` which holds a `ObserveableCollection<StatModifierViewModel>`. Then put ToModel() functions in that turns them back in to their model form when done. You must do all your reads and writes through the view model proxy to get your events raised.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StatModifierType> StatModifierTypes
    {
        get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatModifierType)).Cast<StatModifierType>(); }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemViewModel(Item item)
    {
        if(item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        Name = item.Name;
        Id = item.Id;
        Description = item.Description;

        //This converts our List<StatModifier> to a IEnumerable<StatModifierViewModel>
        var enumerableOfStatViewModels = item.Stats.Select(x => new StatModifierViewModel(x));

        _stats = new ObservableCollection<StatModifierViewModel>(enumerableOfStatViewModels);
    }

    public Item ToModel()
    {
        var item = new Item();
        item.Name = Name;
        item.Id = Id;
        item.Description = Description;

        //This converts our ObservableCollection<StatModifierViewModel> to a IEnumerable<StatModifier>
        var enumerableOfStats = Stats.Select(x => x.StatModifierModel);

        item.Stats = enumerableOfStats.ToList();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StatModifierViewModel> _stats;
    private string _name;
    private string _id;
    private string _description;

    public ObservableCollection<StatModifierViewModel> Stats
    {
        get { return _stats; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _stats)) 
                return;

            _stats = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) 
                return;

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _id) 
                return;

            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _description) 
                return;

            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class StatModifierViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly StatModifier _statModifier;

    public StatModifierViewModel(StatModifier statModifier)
    {
        //This needs to not be null to not blow up the other functions.
        if(statModifier == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("statModifier");

        _statModifier = statModifier;
    }

    public string StatId
    {
        get { return _statModifier.StatId; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_statModifier.StatId, value))
                return;

            _statModifier.StatId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public StatModifierType Type
    {
        get { return _statModifier.Type; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_statModifier.Type, value))
                return;

            _statModifier.Type = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public float Value
    {
        get { return _statModifier.Value; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_statModifier.Value, value))
                return;

            _statModifier.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public StatModifier StatModifierModel
    {
        get { return _statModifier; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

```
public class Stat : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _your_property;
    public int your_property {
        get { return _your_property; }
        set {
            _your_property = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("your_property");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The field I'm trying to observe is a **List<Stat>** so I guess I should create my own IList, INotifyPropertyChanged to capture Add and Remove events?

Comment: @Talemon maybe I'm misunderstanding your scenario. Which classes you **can** and which one you **can't** edit? You want to monitor the change of the number of items or the content of each item?

Comment: You can see the classes here: http://pastebin.com/pmZdu34e
I've called StatModifier as Stat to simplify the question, Stat is a different class in this case. The problem is public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } is observed but Item's Stats field which is a List<StatModifier> is not observed.

Comment: @Talemon If you can't modify `Item` to hold something other than a `List<StatModifer>` then you can't do what you want. You will need to make a `ItemViewModel` which holds a `ObserveableCollection<StatViewModel>` Then put `ToModel()` functions in that turns them back in to their model form when done.

Comment: @Scott that's a great idea! I will try that.

Comment: @Talemon I added a full answer with a example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more property for the Observable Stats. Refer the below code.

```
class Item
{
    private List<Stat> stat;

    public List<Stat> Stats
    {
        get { return stat; }
        set { stat = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Stat> ObservableStats
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<Stat>(stat); }            
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it be connected to the original List? I feel like it would just create a new collection with the original items but it wouldn't relay any changes to the original.